# How to display .html file preventing downloading

Tags: html, object, iframe, embed

I want to display the my.html file in a web page using the iframe tag, but, instead of displaying the contents of the my.html file, the browser downloads the file on the local computer. What should I change in order to make the contents viewables by preventing downloading?

Comment: Can you include your current HTML in the question?

Comment: I restate my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988729/how-to-display-html-file-in-a-web-page-preventing-downloadingand with more info including the code.