# How to display .html file in a web page preventing downloading

Tags: html, object, iframe, embed

I want to display the myfile.html file in a web page using the iframe tag, but, instead of displaying the contents of the my.html file, the browser downloads the file on the local computer. What should I change in order to make the contents viewables by preventing downloading? I also test both embed and object tag but the result remains the same. The code has as follow:

<iframe src="myfile.html"></iframe>

or

<embed src="myfile.html">

or

<object width="400" height="400" data="myfile.html"></object>

Mention: My intention, of course, is to use just one of the above tags, not all them.

Comment: What you want is impossible. It is quite literally impossible to detect "download to use in iframe" v.s. "download to use in embed" v.s. "download to use in object" v.s. "user hitting url directly to download/save to file". **EVERYTHING** you see in your browser has been "downloaded".

Comment: What are you serving your content up with?  You can force a download with HTTP headers.

http://www.symkat.com/force-download-with-http-headers